# Hex Colours in Blender Don't Match Rendered Output (Blender 2.79)

Tags: color, file-format, color-management, compositing-nodes

For some legacy reasons I'm using blender 2.79 to create some images and animations (using some scripts etc). I need these images to match colours I am using elsewhere in a design, so I thought I'd use the Hex values

[image: My output nodes setup]

However, I even with the colour coming straight out of the alpha over node (and it's the same if I plug an RGB node straight into the output) I get completely different values for the colours coming out. I thought it might be a colour management issue, but I can't see any issues there.

[image: My colour management setup]

Does anyone have any advice at all? I really don't want to have to move blender versions at this point, but I do need the colours I specify to come out as specified and not randomly affected.

Some examples of the kinds of difference are rgb(0,0,255) appearing as rgb(25,17, 247) and rgb(255,0,0) appearing as rgb(255,0,22).

I've tried different file formats (png, tga, jpeg etc), to no avail.

Any tips from anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Mike